# React-PDF errors when rendering <Svg> via Ternary conditional

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-pdf

I have an svg header that works perfectly when rendered directly in the tree

```
<Document>
    <Page size="A4">
        <MyHeaderSvg />
    </Page>
</Document>
```

[image]

However when I render it via a Ternary within the render callback of a  element, it errors...

```
<Document>
    <Page size="A4">
        <View render={({pageNumber}) => (pageNumber === 1)
            ? <MyHeaderSvg />
            : <NonSvgHeader />
    </Page>
</Document>
```

[image]

**MyHeaderSvg**

```
<Svg width="555" height="80" viewBox="0 0 555 80">
    <Rect width="100%" height="80" rx="8" ry="8" fill="url(#header-rectangle)"/>
    <Defs>
        <RadialGradient id="header-rectangle" cx="0" cy="0" fr="1">
            <Stop stopColor="blue"/>
            <Stop offset="1" stopColor="lightblue"/>
        </RadialGradient>
    </Defs>

    <Text style={styles.title} x={`${535-20}px`} y="50%" textAnchor="end" dominantBaseline="middle">Some title</Text>

    <G transform="translate(20,21) scale(0.749 0.749)">
        <Path d="M0 47.6941V37.8042C0 35.4188 1.53483 32.1486 6.07125 32.1486C9.60438 32.1486 11.6936 35.4536 11.6936 38.6453C11.6936 41.7456 9.59732 44.8226 6.29155 44.8226C5.26468 44.8226 4.14881 44.4355 3.28243 43.6822V47.6941C3.28243 48.7881 2.59891 49.5178 1.64134 49.5178C0.683769 49.5178 0 48.7881 0 47.6941ZM5.85848 41.8135C7.56766 41.8135 8.4107 40.0355 8.4107 38.5075C8.4107 36.958 7.56766 35.1579 5.85848 35.1579C4.1031 35.1579 3.28243 36.7993 3.28243 38.3951C3.28243 39.9903 4.05763 41.8135 5.85848 41.8135Z" fill="white"/>
    </G>
</Svg>
```

**Experimentation**

I tried commenting out different sections to see the results

| Section commented out | Resulting error |
| --- | --- |
| `Rect` and `Defs` section only | [image] |
| `Text` line only | Original error |
| `G` section only | Original error |
| `Text` and `G` | Original error |
| `G`, `Rect` and `Defs` | [image] |
| `Rect`, `Defs` and `Text` | [image] |

---

**Updates:**

I have been playing with the Repl on React-PDFs website to see where things can break more realtime.

Looks like changing any definitions of numbers from strings into actual numbers ie `x="10"` to `x={10}` helps.

`<Text>` breaks it entirely! There doesn't seem to be any way to get a `<Text>` element included in any way, shape or form.

`<Path>` does seem to work fine as it is defined above, however the `<G>` transform is breaking things as it is defined via a string.